# Installing Rails 3.2.8 into Solaris 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solaris

I'm trying to create a virtual machine with Solaris 11 running Rails 3.2.8. Is there a tutorial or script for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Solaris 11 is distinctly lacking some items that you could almost say are essentials for newer versions of Ruby. And I hear the cries from the Oracle faithful that they are shipping Ruby! Hmm version 1.8 of Ruby and it's nearly 5 years old and only months away from EOL.

So what do you need todo is to build ruby 1.9.3-p125 on Solaris 11, via compiler obviously and I'm using the latest gcc that are included in the Solaris 11 repo. Don't forget to install libyaml too, otherwise we end by with annoying message.

Start with installing libyaml:

```
wget http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
tar xzf yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
cd yaml-0.1.4
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Pretty straight forward no issues.

Installing Ruby 1.9.3-p125 (newer versions does work for me)

```
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz
tar xzf ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz
cd ruby-1.9.3-p125
./configure --enable-shared --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/lib
make
sudo make install
```

Notice that libyaml couldn't be found without specifying ---with-opt-dir

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-solaris2.11]
gem -v
1.8.11
sudo install rails
```

This might not be the right way to solve the installation for Ruby on Rails on Solaris I'm a developer not a system administrator.